# Silverlight - How to get a Hostname from IP?

Tags: silverlight, ip, hostname

I am working on an Business app (SL 4) in which I have to display hostnames from IP.

After trying to use System.Net.Dns (which is impossible due to the class level protection), i'm wondering about the possibilities left to perform this conversion.

Should I create wcf service dedicated to this conversion? Would there a clever way than I'm not seeing?

Thx

Comment: I've create wcf to do the translation. It's run well and make the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my knowledge, There are no direct ways to do this. As you mentioned you can create a WCF method to achieve this.